# What do you call the skin shed by an insect or worm?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the skin shed by an insect or worm? I am sure there's a word for it, and also is there another verb that means "shed a skin"? Because "shed a skin" is a verb and I am wondering if there's a word replacement for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worms don't shed their skin.  Snakes do, but you'd call the shed skin a "snake skin". Generally there is no special word, you just say "'animal name' skin" or "... shell" (depending on how hard it is)

Most insects don't shed their skins as adults. Some do shed a skin as they transform from larvae to adult insects.  For example, cicada will leave "cicada shells" on trees. You occasionally find grasshopper shells too. You also find shed crab shells and the shed skins of spiders.

The verb is usually "shed" but you can also "moult" and "slough" (as per comment) (Moult also means replacing hair or feathers)

There is a highly technical word, but don't use it unless you are writing a scientific paper.  I didn't know this word before researching this answer.

> The technical word is exuvia  (plural exuviae)

Comment: Some other words you can use for the process are moulting and sloughing.

Comment: Yes, moulting seems to be the word I forgot. Not sure if there's a word for the skin though. I keep seeing these skins on the floor of my apartment.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bigger problem than forgetting a word!  What are you finding? Snake skins??

Comment: skin of insect larvas.

Comment: Note: slough is pronounced 'sluff'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey English is such a ridiculous language.

Comment: @newton For what it's worth, I had that in a cupboard once. There was a leak and the floor underneath was very damp, which evidently led to a little "nest" of some kind of little insect.

Comment: "slough" can also be used in the context of menstruation

Comment: @GregSchmit but what will really bake your noodle is "slough" is "sluff" but "Slough" rhymes with "cow".

Comment: @OmarL No, it can't.

Comment: @JamesK Sure it can. "Menstruation is the sloughing off and discharge of mucosal tissues and blood from the uterus", it is a rather clinical sounding description

Comment: @OmarL Slough historically was used for removing a lot of things--almost anything that could be a thin, surface layer, even metaphorically. So you can slough off your coat and you can slough off misgivings. For menstruation, you slough off the *lining* of the uterus (simplification). But I wouldn't say slough is specifically connected to menstruation, any more than the word lining is. https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=slough

Comment: To me at least "snake skin" implies the full depth skin taken from a dead snake, not the thin layer that is shed.

Comment: @PeterGreen I'll disagree with you on that. But what would *you* call what I call a snake skin?

Comment: Snakeskin is what I would understand to be a type of leather used in some shoes and bags.  A snake skin is the naturally shed skin of a snake.  But I'd accept that there is variation in orthography.

Answer (score 7):

An old word that used to be used was "**husk**". The OED has this as an obsolete word for "The coriaceous wing-case of an insect; an elytron", or an archaic word for "The shell or case of a chrysalis; a cocoon." that could be left behind.

Not a modern or technically correct word, but it would be valid as a poetic alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Whether or not insects or worms shed their skin (and at least spiders seem to), the overall word is [**molt**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/molt) (or in UK English, [moult](https://www.lexico.com/definition/moult)). It can be both a verb and a noun:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> intransitive verb
> : to shed hair, feathers, shell, horns, or an outer layer periodically
> // Birds *molt* once or twice a year.
>
> transitive verb
> : to cast off (an outer covering) periodically specifically : to throw off (the old cuticle (see [CUTICLE sense 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cuticle))) —used of arthropods
> // a spider, like a lobster, *molts* its covering as it grows
> — Eugene Kinkead
>
> *noun*
> : the act or process of molting
> *specifically* : [ECDYSIS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecdysis)

Comment: Does the noun refer to the process or to the sloughed off  object?

Answer (score 0):

The word is "[Exuviae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exuviae)"